# Para quê servem os números quando criamos colunas em bancos de dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados

Todo mundo que já trabalhou com bancos de dados já notou que, durante a modelagem de dados de uma tabela, podemos definir um número entre parênteses.

Exemplos:

```
INT(20)
TINYINT(4)
BIGINT(10)
VARCHAR(8)
```

Se cada tipo de dados tem, inerente a si a quantidade de bytes que pode-se armazenar, por que esses números são necessários então? Além disso, o número varia de papel conforme o tipo de dados (por exemplo, `VARCHAR` e `INT`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pode variar de acordo com a implementação de cada banco de dados, mas em geral ele determina o número máximo de caracteres que poderá ser exibido na coluna ou o máximo que poderá ser usado na coluna.

O que certamente não determina é a quantidade de bytes que ocupará na linha. Textos podem ter codificações que um caractere não tem relação direta com a quantidade de bytes ocupados. O armazenamento de números será feito de acordo com com a implementação e cada uma pode ter um consumo diferente.

Esse número que aparece é mais para controle da exibição do dado do que para o armazenamento, ao contrário da crença popular. O tamanho que ocupa é detalhe de implementação.

Então um `INT(20)`, se é que isto é possível, indica que o número pode ter até 20 dígitos na sua representação textual.

Um `VARCHAR(8)` indica que o texto pode ter até 8 caracteres. Alguns bancos permitem que sejam armazenados mais do que isto, alguns vão ocupar 8 bytes porque este tipo não possui codificação *multibyte*, mas depende da implementação. Tem que olhar atentamente a documentação de cada sistema.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Cuidado: no caso do MySQL, o valor entre parênteses nos tipos numéricos determina somente um comprimento **de exibição** dos valores. Cf. http://everythingmysql.ning.com/profiles/blogs/data-type-confusion-what-is-an

Comment: @bfavaretto eu lembro só do MySQL que faz isto, se você ou outra pessoa souber de outro, favor, colocar aqui ou responder com esse detalhe.

Answer (score 6):

No caso dos campos do tipo numérico int, tinyint, bigint, o número entre parênteses significa a quantidade máxima de dígitos. Já para os campos varchar e char, o número indica a quantidade máxima de caracteres.

Comment: Vale informar que esta limitação pode ser usada como validação de campos, como tipo e quantidade de digitos de um campo **CPF**  por exemplo: ```INT(11)``` apenas numero e apenas **CPF**, ```INT(14)``` numeros, para **CPF** ou **CNPJ**, forçaria assim a padronização do desenvolvimento.

Answer (score -4):

Você precisa de um campo que vai guardar o apelido de uma pessoa, os apelidos normalmente não passam dos 80 caracteres, então, ter um espaço para armazenar 3000 caracteres é uma perda desnecessária de memória. Quanto mais caracteres maior é o tempo de salvar/consultar/actualizar seus dados.

Podes não notar em aplicações pequenas mas em aplicações que lidam com grandes quantidades de dados, é um requisito importante para o desempenho da BD e por conseguinte da aplicação.

Comment: Normalmente o espaço de armazenamento coincide com o número (que é o assunto da pergunta) no caso de CHAR e outras colunas fixas de dados, que são a minoria. Um varchar(200) e um varchar(7) com o mesmo conteúdo ocupam o mesmo espaço. No caso de numéricos, o que define o espaço é o tipo em si, não o número de dígitos entre parênteses (um BIGINT(2) e BIGINT(5) tem o mesmo comprimento em quase todos os engines, é só um filtro de saída (e de entrada em alguns DBs). É legal você querer participar, mas é fica a sugestão de uma boa lida nas outras postagens e na documentação das tecnologias antes.